# Child route with id showing as "Cannot match any routes. URL Segment"

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-routing

My routing structure is something like this

```
`programs/48/applications`
```

with id

```
`programs/48/applications/34`
```

Routes are defined like this

```
{ 
  path: 'applications', pathMatch: 'full', component: ApplicationsComponent,
   children: [
      { path: ':id', component: ApplicationComponent }
   ]
},
```

If I go to applications, the app works fine, but if I enter any id after applicatins, it shows as

> Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment:
>   'programs/48/applications/34'

What might go wrong here?

Comment: try ```[routerLink]="['/programs/48/applications', '34']"```

Comment: remove `pathmatch` then try

Comment: if I remove pathmatch, then programs/48/applications automatically turns into programs/48/applications/applications
I don't know why

Comment: @FatemeFazli It doesn't matter how the route is called, the end action is the same

Comment: could it be that you use the path `:id` for the programs/id path as well? Otherwise think about renaming these to `:programId`, and `:applicationId`. I haven't tried it, but it could be conflicting in the router if you use the same parameter id for different path segments

Comment: I also felt the same way, so I tried putting appId instead of id, but still it has the same behaviour!